# Does copying a file cause it to lock

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis

On web server, I have an ASP.NET website with error.txt inside it.

This file always gets written to. And it is in the bin folder.

Should I be concerned if:

1. I go to web server  and open the bin folder
2. Go to web server and open the error.txt

My C# code always writes to it in a share mode `FileShare.ReadWrite`

Is copying the file to another folder using command prompt safer to avoid locking?

Comment: it depends on how your are copying and writing to it.

Comment: Logging errors and other application messages in a DB has a lot of benefits -- particularly when it comes to trying to get AGGREGATES or simply 'find a needle in a haystack'.  You could use LOGPARSER to get similar query behavior with TXT logs but for me SQL is easier and more familiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the application you are opening it with.  For instance, if you open it with Microsoft Word, it will lock the file and other processes will only be able to read it.  However, if you open it with Notepad, the file is not locked and another process can read, write, delete, move, or rename it.

You can test simply by opening a file with the application, and then try to delete, rename, write to, or move the file.  If you can perform any of those actions then you know that your application did not lock it.

Assuming you are just copying it with Explorer, copying the file will lock it for the time it takes to read the file. If it is a small file, this will just be a very few milliseconds.

To ensure that your application doesn't crash if it tries to write to the file while it is locked, put the write operation(s) in a loop that retry if an exception is returned, with a 100 ms wait between tries.

Comment: So if even on server i open with notepad it won't get locked?

Comment: No.  To confirm, simply put a test file on the server, open it with notepad, and then delete it.

Comment: FYI notepad will hilariously not lock the file, but will lock its parent folder. This has broken our build server many many times.